# Can typhoid occur multiple times?

Tags: diet, immune-system, infection, typhoid

Are there any chances of a person being reinfected with typhoid at regular intervals again if they don't follow proper medication and diet, even though they are cured or survived the first infection? Can you gain immunity to typhoid?

Comment: I am not getting why i got the down vote, this is question is not broad and its valid too. people who down vote should give reasons too.

Comment: Probably because it's a somewhat vague question that can be answered with a simple "yes".

Comment: Why are you specifically asking about diet for this question, when recurrence is likely more a question of the immune system? Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: @Formite yes their is a reason according to what i have heard by many if the proper diet is not followed this may occur and again making person's immunity more weak..

Comment: The grammar and style of this question is fairly poor. That might be another reason for downvotes (I'm just speculating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinfection with typhoid fever is certainly possible.

An [older human challenge study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2427859/?page=4) found that individuals with an induced infection were less likely to develop an infection if they had been previously infected, but 23% of them still developed a clinical fever. [Another somewhat old study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC269142/) suggests that unless immunologically boosted, immunity to typhoid fever cannot last for more than ~ 1 year.

Even immunity that arises from [vaccination](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/PDF/rr/rr4314.pdf) wanes and needs a booster after a few years.

Reinfection, regardless of the success of your treatment or diet, is very possible.